# Exclude parent vertex from results

Tags: graph, orientdb

I have a simple graph with one parent and three children:

[image]

Querying for the children, I also get back the parent:

```
select name
from (
  traverse in()
  from (
    select
    from group
    where name = 'Parent'
  )
)
```

Results:

```
name
Parent
Child 1
Child 2
Child 3
```

How can I exclude the parent from the results in the query? I'd rather not process the results in my application code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding where depth is zero seems to do the trick:

```
select name
from (
  traverse in()
  from (
    select
    from group
    where name = 'Parent'
  )
)
where $depth > 0
```

Results in:

```
name
Child 1
Child 2
Child 3
```

Answer (score 1):

To get only the children name, I suggest a query like this:

```
select in('belongsTo').name as Name from Group where name = "Parent" unwind Name
```

Comment: Hi @Adrian, did you have a chance to try my solution ?